# The meaning of 'worst case'

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, algorithms, computational-complexity

When giving bound on convergence rate, complexity and so on, people sometimes will specify it by 'worst case'. What is the meaning of 'worst case'?

Comment: @SBareS I don't know much about this area, but surely there is a typo in your comment?

Comment: @SBareS meant to say worst case time complexity of $O(n^2)$

Comment: Yup, that was a typo. Trying again and being more clear, because I cannot edit my comment.

"Worst case" in terms of time complexity means it is possible to construct an example that runs in that given time, but no more than that. If, for example we say quicksort has time complexity $O(n^2)$, it is possible that some configurations will run in time asymptotic to the $n^2$, but not for, say $n^3$. It might in some (or even most) cases be quicker; in this case it is almost always $O(n\cdot log(n))$, but that cannot be guaranteed in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

As @SBareS mentioned in the comments the worst case analysis is looking at literally that. For algorithm complexity an algorithm may on average run at a different asymptotic rate compared to artificial input which is designed to require more steps or if randomization is involved a run of the algorithm could randomly choose the worst choice every step which may result in a difference in asymptotic growth in run time. For example (again credit to @SBareS) Quicksort where the pivot is chosen uniformly at randomly on average requires $O(nlogn)$ operations. However in the worst case the pivot could partition the elements into a partition of size $1$ and a partition of size $n-1$ for every call leading to a recursion depth of $O(n)$ and each layer requiring $O(n)$ operations resulting in $O(n^2)$ operations

Comment: @SBareS sorry I didn't see you re-added your comment. Feel free to post an answer and I will delete mine since I basically summed up and slightly elaborated on your comment

Answer (score 0):

We have a function, `f`.

That function will take time and space to compute.

Anything you can do with a computer, you can do with pencil and paper.

Space is like the number of pieces of paper it takes to work out the calculation by hand.

Time is the number of lines you have to draw (or erase, if you're creatively reusing paper).

Worst-case means either worst-case space or worse-case time in terms of the number of lines in the input.